# How is the cache behaviour in the API Gateway when you reach the memory limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-api-gateway

I enabled the cache in the API Gateway in some services and want to know what happens if you reach the cache memory limit.

How is the cache behaviour in this case? Is it delete the oldest cached responses? Does it crash?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

When cache is full, old items are evicted using a least recently used (LRU) policy.